# android studio 3, android profiler , show "No debuggable processes"

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

I need a tool like Google Chrome Network tab, but for android.
I found android studio 3 has a new tool like Google Chrome Network tab to show "http" requests. 
My target is find web services called by an specific android application.
I installed apk on an AVD emulator in android studio, but Android Profiler shows "No debuggable processes".

- How can I select my specific android application in this list?
- Is it possible this tool just worked for an android project opened in android studio? (it's very bad if the answer is true, as it will restrict the user)

thanks